# Formatting vscode to handle java code with braces on separate lines

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, formatting

I am looking for a way so that vscode will format my java code such that curly braces are on separate lines. For example...

```
if(x)
{
  dosomething();
}
else
{
  dosomethingelse();
}
```

I've tried installing Java prettier format and Language Support for Java Red Hat, and neither of those seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Java: Open Java Formatter Settings with Preview.` command to open the format settings preview window for modification.

[image]

More detailed settings can be read [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-linting#_editing-formatter-settings).

Answer (score -1):

IDE Eclipse has template for Java code format there on e can change for desired style. Similarly for VS code also it should have template and changing template should give required effect